# How to "refresh" TListBox?

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, rad-studio

I'm creating an app which shows bill numbers, like the one you see at Mcdonald's. A POS system send bill numbers to my app and the numbers are showed in a TListBox called "ListBoxPrep". Then, when the POS system sends my app the number of a bill to be removed, my app gets rid of it from "ListBoxPrep" and add it to "ListBoxReady". Every communication between the POS and my app is done via TCP connection and I have no problem with it.

The problem I'm facing is that I still see the number remain in "ListBoxPrep" even after deleting it by "pItem->Free();". "pItem" is a pointer of TListBoxItem. I want the numbers disappear as soon as my app receives the "delete signal" from the POS and especially without user's interation such as clicking the panel etc. I think of using TTimer, but I have no idea how to make "ListBoxPrep" refresh by itself. Do you have any idea to do that? Any suggestion would be appreciated. I'm using RAD Studio 10.4.

After my app received the "delete signal" from the POS, I still see the numbers at right side. They are supposed to disappear.
[image: After removing the number from right side]

As soon as I click the "ListBoxPrep", the numbers disappear.
[image]

```
void __fastcall TForm1::IdTCPServerExecute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    //We receive data: POS --> Screen(PC)
    String sentDataFromPOS = AContext->Connection->Socket->ReadLn();

    if(sentDataFromPOS .IsEmpty())
    {
        ShowMessage("Data sent from POS is empty!");
        return;
    }

    // 1. Find an order number to move to the right (prep -> ready)
    int indexOrderToRemove = ListBoxPrep->Items->IndexOf(sentDataFromPOS);

    // 2. Add the order number to the "Ready list"
    addNumberToReady(sentDataFromPOS);

    // 3. Remove the order from the "Prep list"
    ListBoxPrep->BeginUpdate();
    TListBoxItem* pItem = ListBoxPrep->ItemByIndex(indexOrderToRemove);
    pItem->Free(); // HERE I have a problem

    // test: To refresh the screen
    LayoutLeft->Visible = false;
    LayoutLeft->Visible = true;

    /*
    ListBoxPrep->Enabled = false;
    ListBoxPrep->Visible = false;
    ListBoxPrep->Enabled = true;
    ListBoxPrep->Visible = true;
    ListBoxPrep->Repaint();
    */
    ListBoxPrep->EndUpdate();
}
```

Comment: How is `sentDataFromKitchen` related to `sentDataFromPOS`?

Comment: Oh, actually `sentDataFromKitchen` is `sentDataFromPOS`. I put `sentDataFromKitchen` by mistake, sorry. I have edited the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component. Its `OnExecute` event is called in the context of a worker thread. As such, it MUST synchronize with the main UI thread when accessing UI controls (that goes for `ShowMessage()` too, BTW).  You can use the RTL's [`TThread::Synchronize()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) (synchronous) or [`TThread::Queue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue) (asynchronous) method for that.

Also, you should not be `Free()`'ing the `TListBoxItem` objects directly. You have the index of the desired item, you can use `ListBoxPrep->Items->Delete()` instead.

If you are using one of the [clang-based compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers), try something more like this:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::IdTCPServerExecute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    //We receive data: POS --> Screen(PC)
    String sentDataFromPOS = AContext->Connection->Socket->ReadLn();

    if (sentDataFromPOS.IsEmpty())
    {
        TThread::Synchronize(nullptr,
            [](){ ShowMessage("Data sent from POS is empty!"); }
        );
        return;
    }

    TThread::Queue(nullptr, // or Synchronize(), your choice...
        [=, this](){ this->orderIsReady(sentDataFromPOS); }
    );
}

void __fastcall TForm1::orderIsReady(String orderNumber)
{
    // 1. Find an order number to move to the right (prep -> ready)
    int indexOrderToRemove = ListBoxPrep->Items->IndexOf(orderNumber);

    // 2. Add the order number to the "Ready list"
    addNumberToReady(orderNumber);

    // 3. Remove the order from the "Prep list"
    if (indexOrderToRemove != -1)
        ListBoxPrep->Items->Delete(indexOrderToRemove);
}
```

If, on the other hand, you are using the ["classic" Borland compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/BCC32), then try this instead:

```cpp
struct orderHelper
{
    String orderNumber;

    orderHelper(const String &orderNumber)
        : orderNumber(orderNumber)
    {
    }

    void __fastcall orderIsReady()
    {
        Form1->orderIsReady(orderNumber);
    }
};

void __fastcall TForm1::orderIsEmpty()
{
    ShowMessage("Data sent from POS is empty!");
}

void __fastcall TForm1::IdTCPServerExecute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    //We receive data: POS --> Screen(PC)

    String sentDataFromPOS = AContext->Connection->Socket->ReadLn();

    if (sentDataFromPOS.IsEmpty())
    {
        TThread::Synchronize(NULL, &orderIsEmpty);
        return;
    }

    orderHelper helper(sentDataFromPOS);
    TThread::Synchronize(NULL, &(helper.orderIsReady));
}

void __fastcall TForm1::orderIsReady(String orderNumber)
{
    // 1. Find an order number to move to the right (prep -> ready)
    int indexOrderToRemove = ListBoxPrep->Items->IndexOf(orderNumber);

    // 2. Add the order number to the "Ready list"
    addNumberToReady(orderNumber);

    // 3. Remove the order from the "Prep list"
    if (indexOrderToRemove != -1)
        ListBoxPrep->Items->Delete(indexOrderToRemove);
}
```

Or this:

```cpp
struct orderHelper
{
    String orderNumber;

    orderHelper(const String &orderNumber)
        : orderNumber(orderNumber)
    {
    }

    void __fastcall orderIsReady()
    {
        try {
            Form1->orderIsReady(orderNumber);
        } __finally {
            delete this;
        }
    }
};

void __fastcall TForm1::orderIsEmpty()
{
    ShowMessage("Data sent from POS is empty!");
}

void __fastcall TForm1::IdTCPServerExecute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    //We receive data: POS --> Screen(PC)

    String sentDataFromPOS = AContext->Connection->Socket->ReadLn();

    if (sentDataFromPOS.IsEmpty())
    {
        TThread::Synchronize(NULL, &orderIsEmpty);
        return;
    }

    orderHelper *helper = new orderHelper(sentDataFromPOS);
    TThread::Queue(NULL, &(helper->orderIsReady));
}

void __fastcall TForm1::orderIsReady(String orderNumber)
{
    // 1. Find an order number to move to the right (prep -> ready)
    int indexOrderToRemove = ListBoxPrep->Items->IndexOf(orderNumber);

    // 2. Add the order number to the "Ready list"
    addNumberToReady(orderNumber);

    // 3. Remove the order from the "Prep list"
    if (indexOrderToRemove != -1)
        ListBoxPrep->Items->Delete(indexOrderToRemove);
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion works very well! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I modified some code in `IdTCPServerExecute` to remove a few compile errors. Here is the code which has worked well. Thank you again, `Remy Lebeau` !

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::IdTCPServerExecute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    //We receive data: POS --> Screen(PC)
    String sentDataFromPos = AContext->Connection->Socket->ReadLn();

    // test
    //sentDataFromPos = "";

    if(sentDataFromPos.IsEmpty())
    {
        TThread::Synchronize(nullptr,
            [=](){ ShowMessage("Data sent from POS is empty!"); }
        );

        return;
    }

    TThread::Synchronize(nullptr, 
// Queue doesn't make the numbers disappear. It doesn't display them at right side either .
        [&, this]()
        {
            this->orderIsReady(sentDataFromPos);
        }
    );
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::orderIsReady(String orderNumber)
{
    // 1. Find an order to move to the right (prep -> ready)
    int indexOrderToRemove = ListBoxPrep->Items->IndexOf(orderNumber);

    // 2. Add an order of the same order number to the "Ready list"
    addNumberToReady(orderNumber);

    // 3. Remove the order from the "Prep list"
    if(indexOrderToRemove != -1)
    {
        ListBoxPrep->Items->Delete(indexOrderToRemove);
    }
}
```

Comment: The *only* difference between `TThread::Synchronize()` and `TThread::Queue()` is that `Synchronize()` waits for the specified function to exit, where `Queue()` exits immediately while the specified function runs in the background. They both use the same queue internally in the main UI thread, so there should be no *practical* difference between `TThread::Synchronize(nullptr, 
[&, this]() { this->orderIsReady(sentDataFromPos); });` and `TThread::Queue(nullptr, [=, this]() { this->orderIsReady(sentDataFromPos); } );` other than the 1st will block `OnExecute` while the 2nd will not.